# Need help understanding install of DOMPDF with Composer and Symfony

Tags: symfony, composer-php, dompdf

I'm having significant amount of troubles trying figure out how to install and use DOMPDF with Composer and Symfony. It is a project written a few years ago and I am completely new to Composer, Symfony and DOMPDF...somebody else told me we were using Composer and Symfony.

I've installed DOMPDF using the puTTy command line interface by:
1. going to the folder where my composer.json is (vendor)
2. running the command "Install dompdf/dompdf" It completed successfully with no errors.
3. Then running the command composer "require dompdf/dompdf" which also completed successfully with no errors.

Then I get lost/confused...

I see instructions that say to edit composer.json with :

```
{
"require": {
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.0.*",
}
```

So here is the new contents of composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "spipu/html2pdf": "^5.0",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.1"
}
```

I've tried using DOMPDF by putting the following line in my PHP code and all I get is a blank page

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
```

There is also an autoload.php which looks like this:

```
//autoload.php @generated by Composer 
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit********************************::getLoader();
```

Following the rabbit hole, autoload_real.php looks like this:

```
// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer
class ComposerAutoloaderInit987ec9019a1b2f978bf00ce76684ede0
private static $loader;

public static function loadClassLoader($class)
{
    if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
        require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
    }
}

public static function getLoader()
{
    if (null !== self::$loader) {
        return self::$loader;
    }

    spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit987ec9019a1b2f978bf00ce76684ede0', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
    self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit987ec9019a1b2f978bf00ce76684ede0', 'loadClassLoader'));

    $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
    if ($useStaticLoader) {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

        call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit987ec9019a1b2f978bf00ce76684ede0::getInitializer($loader));
    } else {
        $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
        foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
            $loader->set($namespace, $path);
        }

        $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
        foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
            $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
        }

        $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
        if ($classMap) {
            $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
        }
    }

    $loader->register(true);

    if ($useStaticLoader) {
        $includeFiles = Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit987ec9019a1b2f978bf00ce76684ede0::$files;
    } else {
        $includeFiles = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_files.php';
    }
    foreach ($includeFiles as $fileIdentifier => $file) {
        composerRequire987ec9019a1b2f978bf00ce76684ede0($fileIdentifier, $file);
    }

    return $loader;
}}function composerRequire987ec9019a1b2f978bf00ce76684ede0($fileIdentifier, $file){if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
    require $file;$GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;}}
```

Additionally, I have 14 folders in the vendor file, which I assume are all packages used with Composer, but I don't see them being required in the composer.json file, and, after installing DOMPDF, I don't see a vendor folder for it. I'd like to remove them, but I don't know what is and is not being used.

I've read the "getting started guides" and I still don't know what I've done wrong.

I'm sure I will have a thousand more questions...thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

a) your composer.json file should be in the root of your project directory and not in the vendor directory.

b) just typing the command

> composer require dompdf/dompdf

in your project directory should be enough to install the libraries in the vendor directory AND to add the line

> "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.1"

in your composer.json.

c) Follow instructions on https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf how to use dompdf.

d) In general when working with composer you have to include the vendor/autoload.php file but in the Symfony framework that will already happen in the app/autoload.php.

> require 'vendor/autoload.php';

e) dompdf does use namespaces. Little example:

```
require "../vendor/autoload.php"; // change path if you need to

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

f) Lot of packages that can be installed with composer use other packages too. If you take a look at the [composer.json from dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/composer.json) you will see that it requires some other packages which composer will automaticly install for you.

## [edit]

Your composer.json is in the root directory of your project. Same for your vendor directory. In your vendor directory there will be a composer directory, that is normal. But execute any commands from your root directory. structure:

```
- [project root] (execute commands here)
       |
       |- composer.json
       |- [vendor]
             |
             |- [composer]
```

If you got stuck just delete the whole vendor directory and composer.json file and again use the command

> composer require dompdf/dompdf

Comment: Thanks, a few more questions:
~ I didn't install Composer, but it seems to be installed in the vendor directory because if I run commands (via puTTy) in the project folder I get an errors, but if I run the commands in the vendor directory, they complete successfully. Additionally, the composer.json file is found in the vendor directory. 
Let's assume:
-project directory: project/includes/part1/page2print.php
-composer installed in: project/vendor

The command "use Dompdf\Dompdf" fails when called in page2print.php. Is the problem where Composer is installed?

Comment: Also, in regards to installing Composer:

I ran the command "composer require dompdf/dompdf" in the vendor folder and got the following messages:

Using version ^0.8.1 for dompdf/dompdf
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: I just noticed that I have a vendor folder in my vendor folder...the dompdf folder is in the second vendor folder.  There is also an additional autoupload.php in the sedond vendor folder.  This is a mess! How can I get it straightened out?

Comment: @FrankB Hi your guide is really helpful, i followed step by step but i still recieve syntax error, unexpected 'use' and Uncaught Error: Class 'Dompdf' not found how i can solve it ? I opened a thread too on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/981407/uncaught-error-class-dompdf-not-found-using-composer-to-install-dompdf

Comment: Try require "../vendor/autoload.php"; and "use Dompdf\Dompdf;". I have updated the example with one extra rule "../vendor/autoload.php".

Comment: @FrankB always getting `syntax error, unexpected 'use' ` if im using use in my php file. Called use after require the file. Dreamveawer mark this line red too. EDIT: im using php 7.0.22 and composer 1.5.2 on my ubuntu 16.04 vps.

Comment: Is your PHP version prior version 5.3.0 ?

Comment: You have to place the USE statement on top of your code and outside any function and classes.

Comment: @FrankB i put it on the first line in my index.php, after `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`. Thats working now thanks a lot, but this error still there: `Uncaught Error: Class 'Dompdf' not found in `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160113/discussion-between-frank-b-and-delato468).